# search and replace tools in linux

Tags: linux, search, ubuntu, replace

What are the best search and replace tools in linux?

I want to find an easy way.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify? What kind of file(s)?  How many files?  How deep a directory structure?  To tools I use for search/replace in source code are different from the ones I use for "Word-like" documents.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [rpl](http://www.laffeycomputer.com/rpl.html).

It will replace strings with new strings in multiple text files. It can work recursively over directories and supports limiting the search to specific file suffixes.

```
rpl [-iwRspfdtx [-q|-v]] <old_str> <new_str> <target_file(s)>
```

Answer (score 3):

`find` for finding files/directories

`grep` or `ack`[1] for searching files

`sed` for search/replace in files

`awk` and `cut` for slicing/dicing text

for anything non-trivial I usually reach for `perl`

[1] http://betterthangrep.com/

Answer (score 1):

`find` and `sed` are the classic tools.